# Git stash and pull issue

Tags: git, github

1. I had some file modified
2. I stashed them
3. Did `git pull origin develop`
4. Git stash pop
5. There was a merge conflict
6. Instead of fixing the conflicts I try to `git checkout` of that file which failed
7. I did `git status`. It showed all files are committed but the one in the conflict. I never did commit
8. I did `git reset HEAD` for the file in the conflict
9. File got reverted but i do not see my other files now which were shown as committed.

Not sure what happened and now my local branch is showing 2000 commits ahead of the master branch.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the losing the changes in the stash, you can simply do

```
git reset --hard origin/branch_name
```

and get your local branch upto speed with the remote branch. Please note that the `--hard` option is destructive. You can try out without the option. but then you might have to deal with a lot of uncommitted changes that might appear